# A model that unifies the strong, EM, weak and gravity forces?

Tags: forces, interactions, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

Does there exist such a model that explains the force clusters (their origin, relations between them): the strong, EM, weak and gravity forces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The electromagnetic and weak forces have been unified into the theory of the [electroweak force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction). The recent discovery of the Higgs boson put the icing on this particular cake.

The strong force is described by the same type of quantum Yang-Mills theory as the electroweak force, however it is not unified with it. There have been several attempts at unifying the strong and electroweak forces, and these are generically known as [grand unified theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory). However none of the attempts has resulted in a convincing unification.

Unifying gravity is even farther away, because gravity can't be described as a Yang-Mills field like the other three forces. Maybe string/M theory will result in a successful unification, but this is probably still a fair way in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not yet.

Long answer:
The strong, EM, and weak forces have been unified via quantum field theories (QFT), while gravity is understood separately via general relativity. The two theories are currently incompatible with each other in the quantum regime.

There are a variety of theoretical efforts underway to unify gravity with the other three fundamental forces, notably in the form of string theories (including M-theory, which posits 11 dimensions, and various brane theories) and quantum loop gravity theories.

Comment: -1 because i) you probably mean QFT rather than QM in your second sentence and ii) I don't think a goal of loop quantum gravity is to unify forces; it only wants to describe gravity, afaik

Comment: You are correct, I meant QFT; I have edited my answer to reflect this. Quantum loop gravity is looking for a way to explain gravity at the quantum level using the framework of QFT. So, in that sense, unification would be a by-product of its success, even if it isn't necessarily an explicit goal.